# Javascript inside XSLT possible?

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

Is it possible to insert Javascript code inside XSLT file?

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
     <span id="Intro" style="font-family:Calibri;" ></span>

     --OTHER XSLT CONTENT HERE--   

    <script>
      document.getElementById('Intro').innerHTML= new Date();              
    </script>
   </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
```

The resulting HTML file doesn't have the date displayed inside the span.

UPDATE: this is not to be rendered by a client. Rather, it's being sent as  the body of an email. Does that change things?

Comment: <span> is not self-closing, and adding a `/>` doesn't change that...

Comment: Thanks dandavis. I also tried the case with <span> </span>

Comment: It's not quite clear if you expect the result of your transformation to contain the date output or if the script does not get executed when the html document is rendered in a browser.

Comment: Well, if the XSLT posted were executed anywhere then `<xsl:template match="">` surely would give an error. As for the script, it is script in the HTML result of the XSLT transformation, it is currently not clear whether you use the result in a browser where script is executed.

Comment: Updated, Martin. In the program it's actually specified, but I took that piece out to make the question more general

Comment: "*The resulting HTML file doesn't have the date displayed inside the span.*" The resulting HTML file is not supposed to have the date displayed inside the span.That will be inserted by the browser dynamically when rendering the file to screen. If you want the resulting file to contain an actual date, it will by necessity be a static date - the date when the XSL transformation took place.

Comment: Re: "**The resulting HTML file doesn't have the date displayed inside the span**." XSLT doesn't know anything about JavaScript, so no one expects an XSLT processor to perform a second pass on the final result and invoke JavaScript. Neither would an XSLT processor invoke a browser passing to it the result of the transformation -- this, if necessary at all, is the responsibility of the invoker of the transformation.

Comment: No self-respecting mail client is going to run javascript on a received email, otherwise spammers wouldn't need to trick you into clicking links.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have JavaScript inside of your XSLT.

However, there can be complications when the JavaScript contains characters such as `<`. You can jump through hoops and play games with CDATA to overcome, but when possible, it is best to externalize the JavaScript and reference it with `<script src="url/to/your.js"></script>`.

Do that for static JS and have small sections of dynamic JavaScript content with variables and arrays of objects that will be used to invoke the static externally loaded JS.